# Algorithm check last node in the tree

Tags: c#, algorithm

```
public void Convert(Node)
{
    StartGrouping();

    DoSomething();

    int childCount = node.GetChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
    {
        Convert(node.GetChild(i));
    }
    if(last_node)
    {
        EndGrouping();
    }
}
```

[image]

What is the correct way to check when we reach the last node (as in the picture).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the last node that has no children: i.e. find the last node of the current level and if it has children go deeper otherwise return it, then you can do it easily:

```
private Node FindLast(Node[] nodes)
{
   var node = nodes.GetLast();
   if (node.HasChildren())
   {
      return FindLast(node.GetChildren());
   }
   return node;
}
```

Comment: My method takes in generic case of a tree when you don't have one root node. You can always pass an array with this one node or edit the method to work with one node instead, but it will be not possible to use if you have a tree without a root node.